# Why can't see session in codeigniter from another controller?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have two controllers

1-connect facebook

2-connect create

When someone want to register he click on **connect_facebook.php** and the controller get his info data and set it in the session, fill the form and send data to **connect_create.php**.
The problem is connect_create controller can't see the session ever, why?

```
<?php

/*
 * Connect_facebook Website
 */

class Connect_facebook extends Website {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        // Load the necessary stuff...
        $this->load->config('account');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper(array('language', 'ssl', 'url'));
        $this->load->library(array('authentication', 'facebook_lib'));
        $this->load->model(array('account_model', 'account_facebook_model'));
        $this->load->language(array('general', 'sign_in', 'account_linked', 'connect_third_party'));
    }

    function index() {
        // Enable SSL?
        maintain_ssl($this->config->item("ssl_enabled"));

        // Check if user is signed in on facebook
        if ($this->facebook_lib->user) {
            // Check if user has connect facebook to a3m
            if ($user = $this->account_facebook_model->get_by_facebook_id($this->facebook_lib->user['id'])) {
                // Check if user is not signed in on a3m
                if (!$this->authentication->is_signed_in()) {
                    // Run sign in routine
                    $this->authentication->sign_in($user->account_id);
                }
                $user->account_id === $this->session->userdata('account_id') ? $this->session->set_flashdata('linked_error', sprintf(lang('linked_linked_with_this_account'), lang('connect_facebook'))) : $this->session->set_flashdata('linked_error', sprintf(lang('linked_linked_with_another_account'), lang('connect_facebook')));
                redirect('users/account_linked');
            }
            // The user has not connect facebook to a3m
            else {
                // Check if user is signed in on a3m
                if (!$this->authentication->is_signed_in()) {
                    // Store user's facebook data in session
                    $this->session->set_userdata('connect_create', array(array('provider' => 'facebook', 'provider_id' => $this->facebook_lib->user['id']), array('fullname' => $this->facebook_lib->user['name'], 'firstname' => $this->facebook_lib->user['first_name'], 'lastname' => $this->facebook_lib->user['last_name'], 'gender' => $this->facebook_lib->user['gender'], 'email' => $this->facebook_lib->user['email'],
                    // not a required field, not all users have it set
                            'picture' => 'http://graph.facebook.com/' . $this->facebook_lib->user['id'] . '/picture/?type=large' // $this->facebook_lib->user['link']
                            )));
                    // send this data to the user submit form

                    $data['locale'] = $this->facebook_lib->user['locale'];
                    $data['session'] = $this->session->userdata('connect_create');
                    $data['facebook_id'] = $this->facebook_lib->user['id'];
                    $data['username'] = $this->facebook_lib->user['name'];
                    $data['gender'] = $this->facebook_lib->user['gender'];
                    $data['email'] = $this->facebook_lib->user['email'];
                    $this->view('site/connect_create', $data);

                } else {
                    // Connect facebook to a3m
                    $this->session->userdata('account_id');
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('linked_info', sprintf(lang('linked_linked_with_your_account'), lang('connect_facebook')));
                    redirect('user/account_linked');
                }
            }
        }

        // Load facebook redirect view
        $this->load->view("site/redirect_fb");
    }

}
```

connect_create controller

```
class Connect_create extends Website {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // Load the necessary stuff...
        $this->load->config('account');
        $this->load->helper(array('language', 'ssl', 'url'));
        $this->load->library(array('authentication', 'form_validation'));
        $this->load->model(array('account_model', 'account_details_model', 'account_facebook_model'));
        $this->load->language(array('general', 'connect_third_party'));
    }

    /**
     * Complete facebook's authentication process
     *
     * @access public
     * @return void
     */
    function index()
    {
        // Enable SSL?
        maintain_ssl($this->config->item("ssl_enabled"));

        // Redirect user to home if sign ups are disabled
        if ( ! ($this->config->item("sign_up_enabled"))) redirect('tttt');

        // Redirect user to home if 'connect_create' session data doesn't exist
        if ( ! $this->session->userdata('connect_create')) redirect('bbbbbb');



        $data['connect_create'] = $this->session->userdata('connect_create');

        // Setup form validation
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="field_error">', '</span>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules(array(array('field' => 'connect_create_username', 'label' => 'lang:connect_create_username', 'rules' => 'required'), array('field' => 'connect_create_email', 'label' => 'lang:connect_create_email', 'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email|max_length[160]')));

        // Run form validation
        if ($this->form_validation->run())
        {
            // Check if username already exist
            if ($this->username_check($this->input->post('connect_create_username', TRUE)) === TRUE)
            {
                $data['connect_create_username_error'] = lang('connect_create_username_taken');
            }
            // Check if email already exist
            elseif ($this->email_check($this->input->post('connect_create_email'), TRUE) === TRUE)
            {
                $data['connect_create_email_error'] = lang('connect_create_email_exist');
            }
            else
            {
                // Destroy 'connect_create' session data
                $this->session->unset_userdata('connect_create');

                // Create user
                $user_id = $this->account_model->create();
                                // Add user details
                $this->account_details_model->update($user_id, $data['connect_create'][1]);


                // Connect third party account to user
                switch ($data['connect_create'][0]['provider'])
                {
                    case 'facebook':
                        $this->account_facebook_model->insert($user_id, $data['connect_create'][0]['provider_id']);
                        break;
                }

                // Run sign in routine
                $this->authentication->sign_in($user_id);
            }
        }

        $this->load->view('site/connect_create', isset($data) ? $data : NULL);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to your `config.php` which is located in **application/config**  folder

set you `$config['cookie_domain']="";`

give a try.

and also try to load session library in auto load config

**application/config/autoload.php**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```